# Using Perl to update HTML

Tags: html, perl

I am having trouble wrapping my head around getting Perl to work with HTML. I am trying to do something I think is simple, but I cant find anything like it online.

Let's say I have a blank web page that has only a button labeled `new`, and when I press it, I want to destroy the button and create two new buttons, one that is a `submit` button, and one `cancel` that creates the old `new` button.

How would I go about doing that, without reloading the page?

From my understanding, the original HTML code would look something like this.

```html
<form action="/cgi-bin/switchButtons.cgi" method="POST">
<input type="button" value="new">
</form>
```

and afterward should look like this.

```html
    <form action="/cgi-bin/switchButtons.cgi" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    <input type="button" value="cancel">
    </form>
```

On pressing `cancel`, it should refer back to the first snippet.

Comment: *without reloading the page* means you'll want to use JavaScript on the front end, not Perl on the back end

Comment: @cajwine: Much as I am fond of Perl and dislike JavaScript, I have to acknowledge that the latter is far better suited to DOM manipulation than Perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that.

`/cgi-bin/switchButtons.cgi` is a Perl program *on the server*.  Clicking on one of the form's buttons sends a request message to the server, which runs `switchButtons.cgi`. The output from that program is the contents of a new web page which is sent back to the client (the browser). Of course that involves loading a new page

You could do it in JavaScript, which is part of the page and runs on the client. You can specify that a button will cause the browser to execute some JavaScript, which could alter the page 9n any way you want. But that doesn't answer your question